Munin dynamic graph zoom (dynazoom) not working - Ubuntu 22.04/Nginx
I know it has been answered again and again, but I can't seem to install fast-cgi, the Ubuntu 22.04 version for it is already installed.
I have configured munin.conf according to all the tutorials, including changing all relevant directories ownership, but when I change things, I get still the ownership error.
Result of munin-check:
check /var/cache/munin/www
check /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp/munin-cgi-graph/*': No such file or directory
# /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp/munin-cgi-graph/* : Wrong owner ( != munin)
check /var/lib/munin/datafile
check /var/lib/munin/datafile.storable
check /var/lib/munin/graphs
check /var/lib/munin/htmlconf.storable
check /var/lib/munin/limits
check /var/lib/munin/limits.storable
check /var/lib/munin/localdomain
check /var/lib/munin/munin-graph.stats
check /var/lib/munin/munin-update.stats
check /var/lib/munin/state-localdomain-localhost.localdomain.storable
check miscellaneous
# /var/lib/munin/datafile : Wrong permissions (664 != 644)
# /var/lib/munin/munin-update.stats : Wrong permissions (664 != 644)
# /var/lib/munin-node/plugin-state : Wrong owner (root != nobody)
Check done.  Please note that this script only checks most things,
not all things.

Please also note that this script may be buggy.

Please also note that this script may be buggy.

My /etc/nginx/conf.d/munin.conf :
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

server {

    listen      127.0.0.1:5440 default_server;
    charset     utf-8;

    # Serve Munin static files
    location /static/ {
        alias /etc/munin/static/;
        expires modified +1w;
    }

    # Serve Munin reports
    location / {
        alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
        expires modified +310s;
    }
    # for dynamic zoom
    location ^~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/ {
       access_log off;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph)(.*);
       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fastcgi-graph.sock;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

Output of /etc/munin/munin.conf:
# Example configuration file for Munin, generated by 'make build'

# The next three variables specifies where the location of the RRD
# databases, the HTML output, logs and the lock/pid files.  They all
# must be writable by the user running munin-cron.  They are all
# defaulted to the values you see here.
#
#dbdir  /var/lib/munin
#htmldir /var/cache/munin/www
#logdir /var/log/munin
#rundir  /var/run/munin

# Where to look for the HTML templates
#
tmpldir /etc/munin/templates

# Where to look for the static www files
#
staticdir /etc/munin/static

# temporary cgi files are here. note that it has to be writable by 
# the cgi user (usually nobody or httpd).
#
cgitmpdir /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp

# (Exactly one) directory to include all files from.
includedir /etc/munin/munin-conf.d

# You can choose the time reference for "DERIVE" like graphs, and show
# "per minute", "per hour" values instead of the default "per second"
#
#graph_period second

# Graphics files are generated either via cron or by a CGI process.
# See http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2 for more
# documentation.
# Since 2.0, munin-graph has been rewritten to use the cgi code. 
# It is single threaded *by design* now.
#
graph_strategy cgi

# munin-cgi-graph is invoked by the web server up to very many times at the
# same time.  This is not optimal since it results in high CPU and memory
# consumption to the degree that the system can thrash.  Again the default is
# 6.  Most likely the optimal number for max_cgi_graph_jobs is the same as
# max_graph_jobs.
#
#munin_cgi_graph_jobs 6

# If the automatic CGI url is wrong for your system override it here:
#
#cgiurl_graph /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph

# max_size_x and max_size_y are the max size of images in pixel.
# Default is 4000. Do not make it too large otherwise RRD might use all
# RAM to generate the images.
# 
#max_size_x 4000
#max_size_y 4000

# HTML files are normally generated by munin-html, no matter if the
# files are used or not. You can change this to on-demand generation
# by following the instructions in http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2
# 
# Notes: 
# - moving to CGI for HTML means you cannot have graph generated by cron.
# - cgi html has some bugs, mostly you still have to launch munin-html by hand
# 
html_strategy cgi

# munin-update runs in parallel.
#
# The default max number of processes is 16, and is probably ok for you.
#
# If set too high, it might hit some process/ram/filedesc limits.
# If set too low, munin-update might take more than 5 min.
#
# If you want munin-update to not be parallel set it to 0.
#
#max_processes 16

# RRD updates are per default, performed directly on the rrd files.
# To reduce IO and enable the use of the rrdcached, uncomment it and set it to
# the location of the socket that rrdcached uses.
#
#rrdcached_socket /var/run/rrdcached.sock

# Drop somejuser@fnord.comm and anotheruser@blibb.comm an email everytime
# something changes (OK -> WARNING, CRITICAL -> OK, etc)
#contact.someuser.command mail -s "Munin ${var:worst}: ${var:group}::${var:host}::${var:plugin}" somejuser@fnord.comm
#contact.anotheruser.command mail -s "Munin ${var:worst}: ${var:group}::${var:host}::${var:plugin}" anotheruser@blibb.comm
#
# For those with Nagios, the following might come in handy. In addition,
# the services must be defined in the Nagios server as well.
#contact.nagios.command /usr/bin/send_nsca nagios.host.comm -c /etc/nsca.conf

# a simple host tree
[localhost.localdomain]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes

#
# A more complex example of a host tree
#
## First our "normal" host.
# [fii.foo.com]
#       address foo
#
## Then our other host...
# [fay.foo.com]
#       address fay
#
## IPv6 host. note that the ip adress has to be in brackets
# [ip6.foo.com]
#       address [2001::1234:1]
#
## Then we want totals...
# [foo.com;Totals] #Force it into the "foo.com"-domain...
#       update no   # Turn off data-fetching for this "host".
#
#   # The graph "load1". We want to see the loads of both machines...
#   # "fii=fii.foo.com:load.load" means "label=machine:graph.field"
#       load1.graph_title Loads side by side
#       load1.graph_order fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#
#   # The graph "load2". Now we want them stacked on top of each other.
#       load2.graph_title Loads on top of each other
#       load2.dummy_field.stack fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load2.dummy_field.draw AREA # We want area instead the default LINE2.
#       load2.dummy_field.label dummy # This is needed. Silly, really.
#
#   # The graph "load3". Now we want them summarised into one field
#       load3.graph_title Loads summarised
#       load3.combined_loads.sum fii.foo.com:load.load fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load3.combined_loads.label Combined loads # Must be set, as this is
#                                                 # not a dummy field!
#
## ...and on a side note, I want them listen in another order (default is
## alphabetically)
#
# # Since [foo.com] would be interpreted as a host in the domain "com", we
# # specify that this is a domain by adding a semicolon.
# [foo.com;]
#       node_order Totals fii.foo.com fay.foo.com
#

